# SQL Server clean up inconsistent dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have dates currently stored as `varchar(1000)` that are in inconsistent formats. I.e. `yyyy-mm-dd` and `dd-mm-yyyy` etc.

What query can I run to clean these up so they are in a consistent format, so I can convert the column datatype from `varchar(1000)` to `date`?

Thanks

Comment: the data are only exists in these 2 format ? Or you have other format ?

Comment: There are six ways to have Date formats if no standard is followed. FOR EX. YYYY-MM-DD. But if delimiter is / or no delimiter, then it has 12 more ways. For ex dd-mm-yyyy or yyyymmdd

Comment: How do you identify the format if a date is like 04-03-2018. It can be either mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy?
FYI: Unless there is a valid reason, storing dates as varchar is not advisable. Obviously for reasons like these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could get ugly if you have many different date formats, possibly including invalid data.  One option would be to assign a new date column using a `CASE` expression to choose the correct format mask:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET date_col = CASE WHEN date LIKE '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}'
                    THEN CONVERT(datetime, date, 105)
                    WHEN date LIKE '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
                    THEN CONVERT(datetime, date) END;
```

You may add conditions to the above `CASE` expression for other date formats.

Comment: This worked great for the example date formats i gave in the question...thanks.  Unfortunately i had many other date formats as well as invalid data to clean up on 220mil rows. but your solution was a big help!!